# Ошибка в MySQL Workbench с RowCount

Tags: php, mysql

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Значение 0 недопустимо для RowCount. RowCount должен быть больше или равен 1. К слову,я пытаюсь сделать форму, где можно будет оставлять комментарии. К
 ДБ подключился,но при отправке комментариев туда ничего не приходит. Это как то связано с ошибкой в воркбенче? Ошибка возникает при обновлении таблицы

```
    $connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=forum; charset=utf8', 'root', '');
$data = $connection->query('SELECT * FROM `comments`  ORDER by date DESC');
if ($_POST['text']) {
    $username = htmlspecialchars($_POST['username']);
    $text = htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']);
    $time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $connection->query("INSERT INTO comments ('username','comment', 'date' )
VALUES ('$username', '$text', '$time')");
    header('Location: index.php');
```

Структура таблицы
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мало данных для осмысленного ответа. Показывайте структуру таблицы и запрос на добавление, приводящий к ошибке.

Comment: когда эта ошибка в воркбенче возникает то? зы: бегом читать про подготовленные выражения и передачу параметров в запросы в PDO

Comment: а чтобы узнать почему не вставляется запись в пхп, надо всего лишь получить сообщение об ошибке после выполнения запроса. и да, имена полей. если уж заключаете в кавычки, то заключайте в обратные.